# Вывод таблицы c ограниченным количеством записей и кнопкой "Select All"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Подскажите как ограничить количество записей в html таблице при помощи js

**UPDATE2**

Вот код с таблицей, как прикрутить? Делаю так

```
<head>
    <style>
        table tbody tr:nth-child(n+6) {
            display:none;
        }

        table.viewall tbody tr:nth-child(n+6) {
            display:table-row;
        }
    </style>
<script 
     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body th:fragment="payments-scheduled(firstBunches, secondBunches, 
failedBunches, firstFriday, secondFriday)">
<fieldset>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="table-container">
        <h3 class="header bolder smaller" th:text="#{bunch.failed}></h3>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-11">
                <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                    <div class="ibox-content">
                        <table class="footable table table-stripped toggle-arrow-tiny">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th width="10" th:text="#{provider.code}">Имя</th>
                                <th width="200" th:text="#{provider.legalName}">Имя</th>
                                <th width="200" th:text="#{providerBalance.balance}">Состояние</th>
                                <th width="100" th:text="#{providerPaymentBunch.paymentDueDate}">Код</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr th:each="entity,iterStat : ${balances}" th:object="${entity}">
                                <td th:text="*{provider.code}"></td>
                                <td th:text="*{provider.legalName}"></td>
                                <td><a th:text="*{balance}" th:href="@{${rootPath}+'/balance/'+ *{id}}"></a></td>
                                <td th:text="*{#ldates.format(providerPaymentBunch?.date)}"></td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <button class="btn-viewall">показать все</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     ....
 <script>
    $('.btn-viewall').on('click',function(){
        $('table').toggleClass('viewall');
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Ошибка

> actual:697 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>       at actual:697

строка

> $('.btn-viewall').on('click',function(){
>           $('table').toggleClass('viewall');
>       });

Comment: что значит отграничить?

Comment: @Cheg, к примеру с сервера пришло данных на 10 строк, показать первых 5, а все остальные показывать по нажатию кнопки "Select All'

Comment: вариант на jquery подойдет?

Comment: @Cheg, да, подойдет!

Comment: @Cheg, upd, гляньте плиз

Comment: а что не так? почему не получается прикрутить?

Comment: @Cheg, ошибку получаю, upd

Comment: у вас jquery не подключен либо подключен неверно

Comment: @Cheg, в <head> вроде он

Comment: Оберните js код в  `$(function(){ /*код сюда*/ })`, вставленный на страницу код исполняется сразу, до загрузки jQuery, а таким способом вы как бы откладываете его исполнение. Аналог `$(document).ready(...)`

Comment: @Евгений, Спасибо большое, все работает! Можно еще вопросик, как быть если таких таблиц на стр несколько?

Comment: @YuriyK обновил ответ с учетом нескольких таблиц на одной странице. еще можно сделать, используя атрибут data-* - тогда необязательно будет помещать таблицу и кнопку в один контейнер

Comment: В скрипте `$('table').toggleClass('viewall');` замените на `$(this).prev().toggleClass('viewall');`. Только теперь у вас кнопки должны идти сразу за таблицами, на том же уровне и без промежуточных тегов, то есть так же как и сейчас.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант #1:

```js
$('.btn-viewall').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.block-with-table').find('table').toggleClass('viewall');
});
```

```css
.block-with-table {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: #ccc solid 1px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

table tbody tr:nth-child(n+6) {
  display: none;
}

table.viewall tbody tr:nth-child(n+6) {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block-with-table">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button class="btn-viewall">показать все</button>
</div>
<div class="block-with-table">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button class="btn-viewall">показать все</button>
</div>
```

Вариант #2:

```js
$('.btn-viewall').on('click', function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).closest('.block-with-table').find('table tbody tr:nth-child(n+6)').show();
  } else {
    $(this).closest('.block-with-table').find('table tbody tr:nth-child(n+6)').hide();
  }
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.block-with-table {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: #ccc solid 1px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

table tbody tr:nth-child(n+6) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block-with-table">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button class="btn-viewall">показать все</button>
</div>
<div class="block-with-table">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button class="btn-viewall">показать все</button>
</div>
```

1-й вариант подойдет больше, если при адаптиве планируется изменять кол-во отображаемых/скрытых строк.

Comment: В CSS `table tbody tr:nth-child(n+6) {...` и JS `$('table tr:nth-child(n+6)')...` разные селекторы, лучше привести к одному виду (добавить/убрать tbody)

Comment: @ЕвгенийМиронов спасибо за замечание, поправил ответ

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно совсем без js:

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
label {
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}
label::before {
  content: 'Show all';
}
input:checked ~ label::before {
  content: 'Hide';
  /* maybe display: none; =) */
}

tbody tr:nth-child(n+6) {
  display: none;
}
input:checked ~ table tbody tr {
  display: table-row;
}
td,th {
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type=checkbox id='toggleRowsVisibility' />
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><th>##</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr><td>2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>3</td></tr>
      <tr><td>4</td></tr>
      <tr><td>5</td></tr>
      <tr><td>6</td></tr>
      <tr><td>7</td></tr>
      <tr><td>8</td></tr>
      <tr><td>9</td></tr>
      <tr><td>10</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br />
  <label for='toggleRowsVisibility'></label>
</div>
```

Добавил `<tbody>` и `<thead>`, что бы заголовок не учитывался как одна из 5 строк