# Отобразить только первые 5 блоков

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день. У меня на странице есть 30 одинаковых блоков (разный только контент: изображения, текст). Как мне вывести только первые 5 элементов с помощью JS?

Я думала сделать это через css, nth-child, но это будут костыли.

Заранее спасибо.

```
<div class="wrapper-block">
 <a href="#">
   <img src="1.jpg" alt="">
   <span class="person">123</span>
 </a>
</div>
```

И вот таких блоков у меня 30, а нужно всего 5. Может этот вопрос будет дубликатом, но я искала, ничего не нашла подходящего.

Спасибо.

Comment: nth-child(nth-of-type) - это не костыль, это вполне нормальное решение

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вывод таблицы c ограниченным количеством записей и кнопкой "Select All"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/686962/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-c-%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-select-all)  , только вместо строк таблицы у вас будут блоки

Comment: Имеете в виду скрыть все блоки, кроме первых 5?

Comment: На JS это будет в такой же мере костыль как и на css :)

Comment: Всем спасибо)) все получилось) через &:nth-child(n+6) {
      display: none;
    }

Answer (score -1):

`$('div.wrapper-block').slice(0, 5)` например

Comment: А вы сами пробовали то, что предложили?

Comment: Пробовал и все отлично работает. В чем у вас проблема?